# bad argument #1 to 'open' (string expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to open a file in my project directory. 
I'm using corona SDK(lua)
I found the variable that return current directory(system.ResourceDirectory)

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "data.txt", system.ResourceDirectory)
print(path)
```

the output is: nil 
after printing nil it return "bad argument #1 to 'open' (string expected, got nil) stack trackback" error

Comment: What's returned by `system.ResourceDirectory`?

Comment: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/ResourceDirectory.html

Comment: I am not speaking about *expected* value but about *actual* one.

Comment: This is because you do not have `data.txt` file in your directory.  The manual says: "If the base directory is system.ResourceDirectory and the generated path points to a non-existent file, nil is returned".  To fix it, place your file `data.txt` where your `main.lua` is located

Comment: What is the line of code where you're calling io.open?